# Python 3.3: LAN speed test which calculates the read & write speeds and then returns the figure to Excel

Tags: python, performance, excel, testing

I'm creating a LAN speed test which creates a data file in a specified location of a specified size and records the speed at which it is created/read. For the most part this is working correctly, there is just one problem: the read speed is ridiculously fast because all it's doing is timing how long it takes for the file to open, rather than how long it takes for the file to actually be readable (if that makes sense?).

So far I have this:

```
import time
import pythoncom
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os

# create file - write speed
myPath = input('Where do you want to write the file?')
size_MB = int(input('What sized file do you want to test with? (MB)'))
size_B = size_MB * 1024 * 1024
fName = '\pydatafile'
#start timer
start = time.clock()
f = open(myPath + fName,'w')
f.write("\x00" * size_B)
f.close()

# how much time it took
elapsed = (time.clock() -start)
print ("It took", elapsed, "seconds to write the", size_MB, "MB file")
time.sleep(1)
writeMBps = size_MB / elapsed
print("That's", writeMBps, "MBps.")
time.sleep(1)
writeMbps = writeMBps * 8
print("Or", writeMbps, "Mbps.")
time.sleep(2)

# open file - read speed
startRead = time.clock()
f = open(myPath + fName,'r')

# how much time it took
elapsedRead = (time.clock() - startRead)
print("It took", elapsedRead,"seconds to read the", size_MB,"MB file")
time.sleep(1)
readMBps = size_MB / elapsedRead
print("That's", readMBps,"MBps.")
time.sleep(1)
readMbps = readMBps * 8
print("Or", readMbps,"Mbps.")
time.sleep(2)
f.close()

# delete the data file
os.remove(myPath + fName)

# record results on Excel
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.visible= 0
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(r'C:\File\Location')
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

# Write speed result
#
# loop until empty cell is found in column
col = 1
row = 1
empty = False

while not empty:
    val = ws.Cells(row,col).value
    print("Looking for next available cell to write to...")
    if val == None:
        print("Writing result to cell")
        ws.Cells(row,col).value = writeMbps
        empty = True
    row += 1

# Read speed result
#
# loop until empty cell is found in column
col = 2
row = 1
empty = False

while not empty:
    val = ws.Cells(row,col).value
    print("Looking for next available cell to write to...")
    if val == None:
        print("Writing result to cell")
        ws.Cells(row,col).value = readMbps
        empty = True
    row += 1


xl.Run('Save')
xl.Quit()

pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

How can I make this so the read speed is correct?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to actually read the file:

```
f = open(myPath + fName, 'r')
f.read()
```

Or (if the file is too large to fit in memory):

```
f = open(myPath + fName, 'r')
while f.read(1024 * 1024):
    pass
```

But operating system could still make read fast by caching file content. You've just written it there! And even if you manage to disable caching, your measurement (in addition to network speed) could include the time to write data to file server disk.

If you want network speed only, you need to use 2 separate machines on LAN. E.g. run [echo server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol) on one machine (e.g. by enabling [Simple TCP/IP services](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-7/Windows-7-Simple-TCPIP-Services-What-How.html) or writing and running [your own](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/echoserver.html)). Then run [Python echo client](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/echoclient.html) on another machine that sends some data to echo server, makes sure it receives the same data back and measures the turnaround time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Is there any way in which I can delete the cache for that particular file?

Comment: I've updated the answer with echo server suggestion and server disk speed concerns.